# Remove "see n. 1" from footnotes biblatex

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Biblatex is formatting my footnotes like so:

[image]

I would like to remove the "see n. 1" or "see n. 30". I'm using the historian package, MWE:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [american]{babel}
\usepackage [english=american] {csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=historian,sorting=nty,
autocite=footnote, babel=hyphen, 
mincrossrefs=1,usetranslator=true,printseries]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\setlength\bibhang{30pt}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\footcite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@book{service,
keywords = {secondary},
title = {Trotsky: A Biography},
author = {Robert Service},
}

@book{pipes,
keywords = {secondary},
title = {A Concise History of the Russian Revolution},
author = {Richard Pipes},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
First time cited.\cite[42]{service} First time cited.\cite[24]{pipes}

Second time cited.\cite[42]{service} Second time cited.\cite[24]{pipes}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

P.S. this is unrelated, but I'd also like to change the title of the bibliography from References to Bibliography.

Comment: Please add to your question the entries for `service` and `pipes` so we can quickly test your example.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Done

Comment: Try `printnoterefs=false` as option, see p. 5 of the [`biblatex-historian` documnetation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-historian/historian.pdf).

Comment: For your PS question try `\printbibliography[title=\bibname]`. With the `title` option one can override the default heading. The default heading for `article`s (and `article`-like classes) is "References" (stored in `\refname`), while for `report`s and `book`s it's "Bibliography" (stored in `\bibname`).

Comment: I get a different output from your example code! See http://imgur.com/1oLVqYE. Do you get the output in the posted image using your exact code?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina No, that's for subsequent comments. There should be two citations for each bibentry in the MWE

Comment: @RenéG Now I am confused. Does your code produce the image in the output? If not, please edit it so we can reproduce the output in the image. Or am I misunderstanding your last comment?

Comment: @moewe Thanks, that worked. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-historian` has an option for suppressing the "see note" string:

```
printnoterefs=false
```

See p. 5 of [the `biblatex-historian` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-historian/historian.pdf).

The `title` option to `\printbibliography` lets you change the title

```
\printbibliography[title=\bibname]
```

The default heading for `article`s (and `article`-like classes) is "References" (stored in `\refname`), while for `report`s and `book`s it's "Bibliography" (stored in `\bibname`).